# Do I misunderstand the definition of diffeomorphism?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, definition, diffeomorphism

I am reading Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Do Carmo.But I am confused of the difinition of diffeomorphism:
A differential mapping $F:V⊂R^{n}→W⊂R^{n}$, where $V$ and $W$ are open sets, is called a diffeomorphism of $V$ with $W$ if $F$ has a differentiable inverse.

I am confused by the differientiable inverse. Does that mean you can define $F^{-1}:W→V$ where all points in $W$ are differentiable, or does it mean you only can find some subsets of $W$ that are differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means two things:

1. The function $F\colon\, V\longrightarrow W$ is a differentiable function which has an inverse $F^{-1}\colon\, W\longrightarrow V$.
2. The function $F^{-1}\colon W\longrightarrow V$ is differentiable, too.

Comment: Now I am confused of the example on the book.If $X:U\subset R^{2}\rightarrow S$ is a parametrization,then $X^{-1}:X(U)\rightarrow U$ may be not differentiable.(But $X(U)$ can be mapped to a plane somewhere).But we also show $U$ and $X(U)$ are diffeomorphic.Why?Do I miss something?

Comment: I don't know. Without further details about that specific map, there's no much I can say.

Comment: V and W must have the same dimension?

Comment: Yes, they do. ${}$

Comment: Thanks,I think I have solved my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$F^{-1}$ has to be differentiable evrywhere. If it's differentiable only on a subset  $\tilde W \subset W$, you may be able to find $\tilde V\subset V$ such that $F(\tilde V) \subset \tilde W$. Then $F|_{\tilde V}: \tilde V \rightarrow F(\tilde V)$ may be a diffeomorphism (if it satisfies the rest of the conditions), but $F$ is not.

Comment: Now I am confused of the example on the book.If $X:U\subset R^{2}\ rightarrow S$ is a parametrization,then $X^{-1}:X(U)\rightarrow U$ may not be differentiable(But $X(U)$ can be mapped to a plane somewhere)But we also show $U$ and $X(U)$ are diffeomorphic.Why?Do I miss something?

Comment: I don't understand the exampeel. Is $X$ some specific function? In general, you're right, $X^{-1}$ doesn't have to be differentiable, but if you are given a specific example, it may happen that it is.